# Countries involved in World War 1(the Great War)

Tags: world-war-one

I can get a list of countries which were involved in World War 1 as Allies but I can't find list of countries who supported Germany in World War 1, basically I can't find list of countries which were enemies to the Allies. Did they have anything in common?

Can someone give a list of Ally and enemy countries. Why did a handful of other countries support Germany?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participants_in_World_War_I

Comment: @KillingTime what is Central Power?

Comment: The Central Powers are the nations allied with Germany. Where you ask about "ally" and "enemy", the more commonly accepted terms are "entente" (ally) and "central" (enemy).  Because the central powers would argue that the other countries are the enemy.  You may wish to ask a new question about why the Central Powers allied with Germany.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: " You may wish to ask a new question about why the Central Powers allied with Germany." I went in that direction with my edit (the new last sentence). I didn't want to do more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The enemies of the "Allies" were known as the [Central Powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Powers). This grew out of the [Triple Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_Alliance_(1882)) that originally included Germany, Austria-Hungary, and Italy.

When war began in 1914, Italy declined to join the other two (and later became an Ally in 1915). Turkey joined Germany and Austria in 1914 because of its emnity to Russia, an Ally. Bulgaria joined the other three in 1915 because of its emnity to Serbia, a minor Ally.

Of all these countries, Germany was the most major country, and the Treaty of Versailles pinned the blame for the war on that country. Her allies played only "supporting" roles.

Comment: At the onset of hostilities, Austria-Hungary was reckoned as a major country as well. Events proved otherwise. Regardless, they were completely dismantled by the peace treaties, as was the Ottoman Empire. By that standard, Germany got off really light.

Comment: @T.E.D.:The GDP of Austria=Hungary was a little more than than  half of France's (counting its Empire) and barely more than either Italy's or Japan's. I would put it at the top of the second rank  powers, rather than the bottom of the first.. The reason why Austria and the Ottoman Empires were dismantled was that they had majorities of non Austrian/Turkish people. Most "German" territory had a majority of Germans.

Comment: I really like your answer, it simplified everything I read so far, thanks